# selecting data depends on the date in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I want to select data from database with Yii Framework. My query is below

```
 $sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('a.status, b.date')
            ->from('check as b')
            ->join('patient as a', 'a.noRM = b.noRM')
            ->join('test_result as c', 'b.ID = c.ID')
            ->where('b.date between '.$start_date.' and '.$end_date)
            ->queryAll();
```

I think there is some trouble with it because It give me zero (`array()={}` ) while in database there are data where date field between `$start_date` and `$end_date`.
If I change the syntax without clause where, So my syntax become :

```
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('a.status, b.date')
            ->from('check as b')
            ->join('patient as a', 'a.noRM = b.noRM')
            ->join('test_result as c', 'b.ID = c.ID')
            ->queryAll();
```

The result is true, nothing problem with it. Or I change my Syntax with :

```
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('a.status, b.date')
            ->from('check as b')
            ->join('patient as a', 'a.noRM = b.noRM')
            ->join('test_result as c', 'b.ID = c.ID')
            ->where('b.noRM = '.$noRM)
            ->queryAll();
```

The result is also true. So I think there is some problem when I select data depends on the date.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in initial sql query was with missing quotas `'` for dates in `->where()`

```
->where('b.date between '.$start_date.' and '.$end_date) // Wrong
```

you should enclose each date in `'date'` like this

```
->where("b.date between '".$start_date."' and '".$end_date."'") // Correct
```

so in your final sql query it will look like `WHERE b.date between '2015-12-1' and '2015-12-27'`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try This:-

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('attributeName', 'value1', 'value2');
$user = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```